# android studio java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: android

```
12/24 23:28:13: Launching 'app' on Nexus 6 API 24.
$ adb shell am start -n "dab.scuffedbots/dab.scuffedbots.laya.Main2Activity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3779 on device 'Nexus_6_API_24 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: dab.scuffedbots, PID: 3779
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{dab.scuffedbots/dab.scuffedbots.laya.Main2Activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dab.scuffedbots.laya.Main2Activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/dab.scuffedbots-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/dab.scuffedbots-2/lib/x86, /data/app/dab.scuffedbots-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dab.scuffedbots.laya.Main2Activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/dab.scuffedbots-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/dab.scuffedbots-2/lib/x86, /data/app/dab.scuffedbots-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 

Debugging But i dont know where the exception goes
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the follow solution:

1.Check the Classpath:
Ensure that the Main2Activity class is correctly named and exists in the specified path. Verify for any typos in the class or path.

2.Check the Manifest Entry:
Confirm that Main2Activity is correctly declared in the manifest. Verify that the entry in the  tag is accurate and matches the actual classpath.

```
<activity android:name="dab.scuffedbots.laya.Main2Activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

3.Check Build Configuration:
Ensure that the class is appropriately compiled and included in the APK file during the build process.

4.Clean and Rebuild:
Attempt to clean and rebuild your project. Sometimes, build issues can lead to such errors.

5.Proguard:
If Proguard is enabled, it might be removing certain classes if not properly configured. Inspect the Proguard configuration and add rules if necessary to exclude the affected classes.